# Basic formalities when considering random numbers

Tags: sampling, random-variable

Suppose we are interested in randomly picking numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ with the uniform distribution. If I want to write a mathematical text about this, it can be done by saying that $X$ is a random variable with uniform distribution in $[0,1]$, or $X\sim U[0,1]$ for short. Then I can analyze the expected value of $X$, it's variance, some particular probabilities and so on. By analyzing $X$, I'm analyzing the process of picking numbers described above.

In practice, I'm able to do that, and if asked to formalize more about this random variable, I would introduce a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, say that $X:\Omega\to[0,1]$ is a measurable function, talk about it's density function and so on. Everything ok to this point.

Usually the sample space $\Omega$ stands for some *concrete* (real world) problem we are interested in and $X$ translates this concrete in numbers (so we can use mathematics). But in this case there is no concrete, we are only interested in numbers. We really just want the codomain of $X$, not the domain. So I considered two explanations of how we should interpret $\Omega$:

**1)** We just let $\Omega$ undefined. It is there just to formalize the notion of a measurable function.

**2)** $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $X(\omega) = \omega$, for all $\omega\in [0,1]$.

**My two questions are:** How should we interpret $\Omega$ in this situation? And what are the differences between my two interpretations (is one of them *more right*)?

Comment: I would say defining $\Omega$ as anything but $[0,1]$ is redundant since the uniform distribution sounds like the reference measure in this problem.

Comment: @Xi'an So $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $X(\omega) = \omega$ is the best choice?

Comment: ...while I would not use "best", this would surely be my "default" choice!